# How to use Twist messages in robo-arm?

Tags: microcontroller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
We have arm with servo joints,we are  writing controller for it, and i don't know how correctly apply Twist messages,to control it.

Some questions:

1)If task is only to rotate angles of  servos , i need only "angular" field of Twist?

2. If arm has **4** servos, i have to send **4** Twist for  each of them? How should i do this? Arrays, separated topics or otherwise?
3. Twist not used for this tasks and this questions don't make sense.

I will  be appreciate any advice. Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212095/how-to-use-twist-messages-in-robo-arm?/) by [tambel](https://answers.ros.org/users/22448/tambel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure, but I don't think its usually the case that manipulators expose a `geometry_msgs/Twist` interface. So i'd go for your option 3.

Most of the planners ROS uses out-of-the-box generate plans in *joint space*, so a [trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory](http://docs.ros.org/api/trajectory_msgs/html/msg/JointTrajectory.html) interface would seem like a logical thing to have. You can probably look at some other implementations for inspiration.

---

Edit: if you're starting from scratch: be sure to take a look at [ros_control](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control), and for arms/manipulators, the [joint_trajectory_controller](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_trajectory_controller). Could save you a lot of work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tambel](https://answers.ros.org/users/22448/tambel/) on 2015-06-25**:
Thank you, it really helps!